# How to use GitHub to make a public gist? What is the procedure?

Tags: github, gist

I want to create a public gist in GitHub. I've been on YouTube and in Google search but have not found an answer to this question. And I don't see an answer in Stackoverflow to this question. This my seem trivial to some of you but I'm not so savvy in the tech world. I have a GitHub account. I did the tutorial in the Read Me Guide where I learned about repositories, branch, commit and pull request. I was in StackExchange chat room where someone asked me to make a public gist of my code that I was asking help with. Now I want to create a public gist of my code. On the Gist page I see a place to where I think the code is suppose to go. I see an Add File tab.  But nothing happens when I click on it.The app won't let me just paste in my code. I see a place for a gist description. And I see a place for a file name including extension. But how do I place my code to create a public gist? Where does it go? Somebody help, please. After some more searching I think I got an answer. A Gist is just a repository. Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are logged in on GitHub:

1. [Visit the Gist page](https://gist.github.com/)
2. Paste your code in the text box directly underneath where it lets you set a file name;
3. Then press 'create public gist' in the bottom right.

For more information on this, [visit the official docs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/).

Comment: I don't want to sound stupid but I tried pasting in my code before I posted this question. I just went back to GitHub and clicked the gist link, added my description and file name including extension but the app won't let me paste. Nothing happens when I right click paste or control v in windows 10.

Comment: My bad. I went back and this time it worked. I right clicked and the code pasted in the text box. Thank you for putting up with me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create public gist repository on github then following steps are there,

There is a GithubHist(https://gist.github.com/) available to share you code publicly over the internet.

One of the advantage to use this is that when you create repository in GithubHist, one same repository will be created on https://bl.ocks.org

This will run your code and show output to the user.

Steps to use GithubHist

1. Login on Github.
2. There is a Gist option on top of then menu. Click on this.
3. It will redirect you on https://gist.github.com/
4. Here in Gist description give Title of your project.
5. Now create index.html file. This file runs by default when you go on https://bl.ocks.org with your repository location.
6. Now you can add as many files that you need in your project here.Just click on add file.
7. To add License,you need to add license.txt file and add contents of the license.
8. At last click on “Create public gist” or “Create Secret gist” option at bottom.

To add Background image of your project on https://bl.ocks.org

1. Get git clone of project to your local machine.
2. Create file with name “thumbnail.png” with dimension 230px * 120px.
3. Add this file to your project.
4. Commit and Push changes.

It’s Done now.

Check your Project with links

https://gist.github.com/yourName/ProjectId Source of project

https://bl.ocks.org/yourName/ProjectId output of project with source

Please see my blog on medium

https://medium.com/@thakkarchintu5/using-githubgist-on-github-f4f0944bbc80

also check gist repository that I have created

https://bl.ocks.org/ChandrakantThakkarDigiCorp